# Multiselect con select 2 dependiente de un select no me muestra información al dar clic en recuadro update de un modal

Tags: javascript, php, select2

Estoy teniendo un incoveniente con el multiselect: cuando me abre el modal para actualizar datos de la tabla, el recuadro me lo trae en blanco y no me cargan las opciones que coloqué. El multiselect depende de lo que se elija en el select.

Agrego más información con respecto a mi código:

```js
$("#inst_id").change(function () {
    var inst_id = $(this).val();
    $.post(
        "../../controller/equipos.php?op=combo",
        { inst_id: inst_id },
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#id_equipo").html(data); // Actualiza el select normal
            
        }
    );
});

$("#id_equipo").select2();
**/* TODO: Mostrar Informacion en los inputs */**
$.post(
    "../../controller/cliente.php?op=mostrar",
    { id_client: id_client },
    function (data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data);

      var fechaOriginal = data.c_fechaestab;
      if (fechaOriginal) {
        var partesFecha = fechaOriginal.split("-");
        if (partesFecha.length === 3) {
          var nuevaFecha =
            partesFecha[2] + "-" + partesFecha[1] + "-" + partesFecha[0];
          $("#c_fechaestab").val(nuevaFecha);
        }
      }

      $("#id_client").val(data.id_client);
      $("#id_cdt").val(data.id_cdt);
      $("#id_clase").val(data.id_clase);
      $("#client_num").val(data.client_num);
      $("#client_nom").val(data.client_nom);
      $("#c_escritura").val(data.c_escritura);
      $("#c_notario").val(data.c_notario);
      $("#c_nronotaria").val(data.c_nronotaria);
      $("#c_distrito").val(data.c_distrito);
      $("#c_folio").val(data.c_folio);
      $("#c_folio2").val(data.c_folio2);
      $("#c_vol").val(data.c_vol);
      $("#c_libro").val(data.c_libro);
      $("#c_seccion").val(data.c_seccion);
      $("#c_seccion2").val(data.c_seccion2);
      $("#c_fechaestab").val(data.c_fechaestab);
      $("#c_registropublico").val(data.c_registropublico);
      $("#legal_nom").val(data.legal_nom);
      $("#legal_ape").val(data.legal_ape);
      $("#legal_escritura").val(data.legal_escritura);
      $("#legal_fecha").val(data.legal_fecha);
      $("#legal_notario").val(data.legal_notario);
      $("#legal_notaria").val(data.legal_notaria);
      $("#legal_distrito").val(data.legal_distrito);
      $("#legal_folio").val(data.legal_folio);
      $("#legal_folio2").val(data.legal_folio2);
      $("#legal_vol").val(data.legal_vol);
      $("#legal_libro").val(data.legal_libro);
      $("#legal_seccion").val(data.legal_seccion);
      $("#legal_seccion2").val(data.legal_seccion2);
      $("#legal_registro").val(data.legal_registro);
      $("#client_rfc").val(data.client_rfc);
      //$('#client_nom').html(data.client_nom);
      $("#client_tel").val(data.client_tel);
      //$('#cliente_telefono').html(data.client_tel);
      $("#c_calle").val(data.c_calle);
      //$('#cliente_calle').html(data.c_calle);
      $("#c_numext").val(data.c_numext);
      //$('#cliente_numeroexterior').html(data.c_numext);
      $("#c_cp").val(data.c_cp);
      //$('#cliente_codigo').html(data.c_cp);
      $("#c_colonia").val(data.c_colonia);
      //$('#cliente_colonia').html(data.c_colonia);
      $("#c_estado").val(data.c_estado);
      //$('#cliente_estado').html(data.c_estado);
      $("#c_correo").val(data.c_correo);
      $("#inst_id").val(data.inst_id);
      var areas = data.id_equipo.split(",");
      console.log(areas);
      $('#id_equipo').val(areas).trigger('change');
      $("#cons_inversion").val(data.cons_inversion);
      $("#cons_min").val(data.cons_min);
      $("#cliente_antiguedad").val(data.cliente_antiguedad);
      $("#cons_duracion").val(data.cons_duracion);

      //$('#cliente_correo').html(data.c_correo);
      imgContenedor(data.contrato_file, "contrato_file");

      imgContenedor(data.poder_file, "poder_file");
      imgContenedor(data.acta_file, "acta_file");
      imgContenedor(data.pagare_file, "pagare_file");
      imgContenedor(data.domicilio_file, "domicilio_file");

      //$('#foto_img').attr('src',datos[4]);
    }
);
```

A continuación muestro mi modal:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label class="form-label" for="exampleInput">Instalacion</label>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" id="inst_id" name="inst_id" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" <?php echo $readonly; ?>></select>
</div>

<div class="select2-purple">
    <label class="form-label" for="id_equipo">Equipos</label>
    <select class="select2" id="id_equipo" name="id_equipo[]" multiple></select>
</div>
```

**Muestro también el combo que me trae los datos o me carga los datos de la based de datos:**
Espero pueda ser de ayuda

```js
case "combo":
    $datos = $equipo->get_equipos($_POST["inst_id"]);
    $html = "";
    $html .= "<option label='Seleccionar...'></option>";
    if (is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) > 0) {
        foreach ($datos as $row) {
            $html .= "<option value='" . $row['id_equipo'] . "'>" . $row['equip_descrip'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo $html;
    }
    break;
```

**Y por último el mostrar que me trae la información o me carga la información:**

```js
**case "mostrar";**
    $datos=$cliente->get_clienteuno_x_id($_POST["id_client"]);  
    if(is_array($datos)==true and count($datos)>0){
        foreach($datos as $row)
        {   
            $output["id_client"] = $row["id_client"];
            $output["usu_id"] = $row["usu_id"];
            $output["id_cdt"] = $row["id_cdt"];
            $output["com_nom"] = $row["com_nom"];
            $output["id_clase"] = $row["id_clase"];
            $output["clase_nom"] = $row["clase_nom"];
            $output["c_escritura"] = $row["c_escritura"];
            $output["c_notario"] = $row["c_notario"];
            $output["c_nronotaria"] = $row["c_nronotaria"];
            $output["c_distrito"] = $row["c_distrito"];
            $output["c_folio"] = $row["c_folio"];
            $output["c_folio2"] = $row["c_folio2"];
            $output["c_vol"] = $row["c_vol"];
            $output["c_libro"] = $row["c_libro"];
            $output["c_seccion"] = $row["c_seccion"];
            $output["c_seccion2"] = $row["c_seccion2"];
            $output["c_fechaestab"] = $row["c_fechaestab"];
            $output["c_registropublico"] = $row["c_registropublico"];
            $output["legal_nom"] = $row["legal_nom"];
            $output["legal_ape"] = $row["legal_ape"];
            $output["legal_escritura"] = $row["legal_escritura"];
            $output["legal_fecha"] = $row["legal_fecha"];
            $output["legal_notario"] = $row["legal_notario"];
            $output["legal_notaria"] = $row["legal_notaria"];
            $output["legal_distrito"] = $row["legal_distrito"];
            $output["legal_folio"] = $row["legal_folio"];
            $output["legal_folio2"] = $row["legal_folio2"];
            $output["legal_vol"] = $row["legal_vol"];
            $output["legal_libro"] = $row["legal_libro"];
            $output["legal_seccion"] = $row["legal_seccion"];
            $output["legal_seccion2"] = $row["legal_seccion2"];
            $output["legal_registro"] = $row["legal_registro"];
            $output["client_num"] = $row["client_num"];
            $output["client_nom"] = $row["client_nom"];
            $output["client_rfc"] = $row["client_rfc"];
            $output["client_tel"] = $row["client_tel"];
            $output["c_calle"] = $row["c_calle"];
            $output["c_numext"] = $row["c_numext"];
            $output["c_cp"] = $row["c_cp"];
            $output["c_colonia"] = $row["c_colonia"];
            $output["c_estado"] = $row["c_estado"];
            $output["c_correo"] = $row["c_correo"];
            $output["inst_id"] = $row["inst_id"];
            $output["inst_nom"] = $row["inst_nom"];
            $output["id_equipo"] = $row["id_equipo"];
            $output["equip_descrip"] = $row["equip_descrip"];
            $output["cliente_estado"] = $row["cliente_estado"];
            $output["cliente_estnombre"] = $row["cliente_estnombre"];
            $output["cons_inversion"] = $row["cons_inversion"];
            $output["cons_min"] = $row["cons_min"];
            $output["cliente_antiguedad"] = $row["cliente_antiguedad"];
            $output["cons_duracion"] = $row["cons_duracion"];
            $output["contrato_file"] = $row["contrato_file"];
            $output["poder_file"] = $row["poder_file"];
            $output["acta_file"] = $row["acta_file"];
            $output["pagare_file"] = $row["pagare_file"];
            $output["domicilio_file"] = $row["domicilio_file"];
            $output["identificacion_file"] = $row["identificacion_file"];
            $output["estadoc_file"] = $row["estadoc_file"];
            $output["opinion_file"] = $row["opinion_file"];
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
    break;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al final, ¿el select2 es para _id_equipo_ o _id_equipos_? ¿Dónde está _id_equipos_ en tu html?

Comment: para id_equipo solamente

Comment: Entonces, ¿por qué en tu código aparece `$("#id_equipos").select2();`?

Comment: ya lo modifique disculpa entre prueba y prueba se me paso quitarlo

Comment: Ya que editaste erróneamente dos veces la misma parte: ten en cuenta que los bloques de código se forman con triples acentos graves (_backticks_, `). Has intentado colocar negritas en parte del código, es por eso que se ven los asteriscos como tal.

Comment: disculpa como apenas ando posteando aun no encuentro la manera correcta de subir los apartados